# Core Data NSPredicate with SQLITE store

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

This code returns 0 objects which is not correct. However, when removing the predicate, the fetch request returns all objects.

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription                                              entityForName:@"Person"  inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K beginswith '%@' ",
                    @"FullName", searchText];

//NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PersonID == %@", searchText]; Works fine


NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
 [request setPredicate:pr];
NSArray * arr = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The FullName attribute contains unicode data(Arabic).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
NSPredicate * pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FullName beginswith %@", searchText];
```

Comment: +1 Using the `%@` substitution will automatically interpret the value as a string.  There's no need for the single quotes around it.  If you needed to add the single quotes, then there'd be no need for the `%K` substitution.

Comment: @Dave Just curious what does the `%K` format specifier do? I have never used it and couldn't find any documentation on it in the Apple String Programming Guide or the IEEE PRINTF Specifications.

Comment: it's used for substituting a non-quoted string value, so it's primarily used for key paths (hence `%K`).  Internally, it becomes an `NSKeyPathExpression` instead of an `NSConstantValueExpression` (which it would be if you used any other substitution format).  `%K` is specific to `NSPredicate` format strings.  I don't think I've encountered them anywhere else.